# Not able to archive Swift app and upload to the app store without "Your app can't contain standalone executables or libraries" error

Tags: swift, xcode, archive

After trying to investigate this, I've seen this in a few other places, namely the Flurry Analytics framework, but their solutions don't seem to apply to my issue.

The error is referencing a file with my app's name and a .o extension[image]

My build log shows it twice under two "CompileSwift normal arm64" sections:

> "/Users/Admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App_Name-fglhmhjmskcjuedbcbpinrnjxaey/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App
>   Name/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/App Name.build/Release-iphoneos/App
>   Name.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AppNamePrefs.o" -o

Searching for anything .o in Xcode turns up nothing, but maybe I could navigate to what it shows in the build log, but I don't know how that would solve my issue, aside from attempting to delete it, but I'm not sure if it's the right approach because I have no idea what this file is for.

Comment: Did you at any point start to add a preference bundle so your app would have custom preferences in Settings.app? If so it may not have been added correctly (or not fully removed if you made one and got rid of it later).

Comment: I don't believe so. I do have a swift file called [AppName]Prefs.swift (similar to the [AppName]Prefs.o filename!) and a preferences.plist file that it writes preferences to. It automatically adds the default preferences like the ability to use the camera, photo library and such to Settings.app, but none of my custom settings.

Comment: That `.swift` file is where the `.o` file is coming from. The compiler takes the source code and compiles each object into a `.o` file.

Comment: Not sure why is it being perceived as a bundle though…

Comment: Think I found it. So obvious. It's in my Copy Bundle Resources.

Comment: Well thats not normal behavior! Source code should only be in the Compile Sources build phase. Wonder how it got in there…

Comment: I have no idea!